# Is there an alternate way (a more efficient way) to code this so that it can run faster?

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

Is there an alternate way (a more efficient) to code this -- to reduce the wall clock time (i.e make it go faster)?

```
from uszipcode import ZipcodeSearchEngine
search = ZipcodeSearchEngine()
order_line["STATE"] = pd.Series(order_line['CUSTOMER_ZIP_CODE']).apply(lambda x: search.by_zipcode(x).State)
```

Comment: please explain what you're trying to achieve. And the expected output too.

Comment: use iloc or loc

Comment: I have a set of US zipcodes and I am trying to create a new column of states (as in state..country..city)  to which these zipcodes belong.

Answer (score 1):

If there are many lines with the same zip codes and `search.by_zipcode()` is slow, you could use `lru_cache`:

```
from uszipcode import ZipcodeSearchEngine
from functools import lru_cache

search = ZipcodeSearchEngine()

@lru_cache()
def get_state(zipcode):
    return search.by_zipcode(x).State

order_line["STATE"] = pd.Series(order_line['CUSTOMER_ZIP_CODE']).apply(get_state)
```